I had been banned from Safe API
We are using the safe API for our Corporate wallets in Trustyfy.
During the last weeks, we have been testing the app and it seems that Safe has banned us on staging.trustyfy.com, what can we do?
Any help would be appreciated.
Best!

You should contact the Safe team using their official channels.
